# How to populate a dataframe column based on the value of another column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, comparison, geopandas

Suppose I have 3 dataframe variables: `res_df_union` is the main dataframe and `df_res` and `df_vacant` are subdataframes created from `res_df_union.` They all share 2 columns called `uniqueid` and `vacant_has_res`. My goal is to compare the `uniqueid` column values in `df_res` and `df_vacant`, and if they match, to assign `vacant_has_res` in `res_df_union` with the value of 1.
*Note: I am using `geoPandas` (gpd Dataframe) instead of just `pandas` because I am working with spatial data but the concept is the same.

```
res_df_union = gpd.read_file(union, layer=union_feat)

df_parc_res = res_df_union[res_df_union.Parc_Res == 1]
unq_id_res = df_parc_res.uniqueid.unique()

df_parc_vacant = res_df_union[res_df_union.Parc_Vacant == 1]
unq_id_vac = df_parc_vacant.uniqueid.unique()

vacant_res_ids = []
for id_a in unq_id_vac:
for id_b in unq_id_res:
     if id_a == id_b:
        vacant_res_ids.append(id_a)
```

The code up to this point works. I have a list of `uniqueid`'s that match. Now I just want to look for those unique id's in `res_df_union` and then assign `res_df_union['vacant_has_res']` = 1. When I run the following, it either causes my IDE to crash, or never finishes running (after several hours). What am I doing wrong and is there a more efficient way to do this?

```
def u_row(row, id_val):
  if row['uniqueid'] == id_val:
     return 1

for item in res_df_union['uniqueid']:
    if item in vacant_res_ids:
        res_df_union['Has_Res_Association'] = res_df_union.apply(lambda row: u_row(row, item), axis = 1)
```

Comment: Without sample data, all I can say is try `res_df_union['uniqueid'].isin(vacant_res_ids)` and `loc`.

Comment: Using your method(`isin`) throws the error:`ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`.  So, `uniqueid` data would just look like this `['DC7008', 'DC7009'....'DC8999'].` And `vacant_res_ids` would be a similar list of just the items that matched. How would you use `loc` in this situation. And does the `.apply` method look correct?

Comment: `s = res_df_union['uniqueid'].isin(vacant_res_ids)` gives you the whole series where `uniqueid` is in `vacant_res_ids`, which you can use to update with loc: `res_df_union.loc[s, column] = something`.

Comment: I tried `res_df_union.loc[s, res_df_union.Has_Res_Association] = 1` but got a `ValueError: cannot index with vector containing NA / NaN values`. Any ideas?

Comment: try: `res_df_union.loc[s,'Has_Res_Association'] = 1`

Comment: That totally worked! Sorry, I am new to the syntax. Appreciate the assist.